# Migrate data from MySQL to SQL Server, database names differ

Tags: sql-server, mysql, migration

I'm using `SQL Server Migration Assistant` for data migration from MySQL to SQL Server. I would like to know whether it is possible to migrate data from databases of different names but tables inside databases have the same names.

Comment: If you are doing it via script then it won't cuz there is a syntax variation. as SQL uses `IDENTITY` and MySQL uses `AUTO_INCREMENT` ... be aware

Comment: Are you using any tool?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can migrate database and rename database name.